# Localhost refused to connect using laravel sail (Docker)

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

My application was running smoothly until i installed laravel octane following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/octane) and then localhost has refused to work. I have my installation running on the docker installation for [windows](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows).
Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
       image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
       volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
       networks:
           - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

my `/docker/8.0/supervisord.config` file where i edited the command according to the octane doc to serve my application using swoole server instead of php development server.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan octane:start --server=swoole --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

I don't know what else to do, i have tried rebuilding the sail image multiple times but still it wont work on http://localhost:8000 or http://0.0.0.0:/8000

Comment: What port did you configure in your .env? Default is 80 instead of 8000

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday, I was worried about it, but I solved it.

It was a simple thing!

```
ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
```

↓

```
 ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:8000'
```

Let's access to http://localhost!

I'm sure I can do it.

Comment: I had the same problem, http://localhost is serving but octane server is not running, any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to connect to the docker container on port 8000 and 80 I think this would be the correct configuration:

```
ports:
    - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80' 
    - '8000:80'
```

This will open 80 and 8000 to the wild.

This is useful if you want to run laravel sail and make it available as an API for something like React/NestJS.